# Color fade with setTimeout

Tags: javascript

Long story short, why doesn't this work? It seems to be running the setTimeout line once, but it won't repeat. It's supposed to decrease the alpha of the target element's background color by 0.1 every 500ms until it reaches zero, but by my reckoning it only makes it to 0.9 before the function stops... It's insanely simple but I can't find any info here or elsewhere which addresses something like this.

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, got it working with setInterval. CSS definitely provides a more elegant solution, but I should have mentioned that this is for an assignment in which we're supposed to use javascript instead.

```
function highlight(which){
    var target=document.getElementById(which);
    var a_value=1.0;
    if(a_value<0){
      return;
    }
    target.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,0,"+a_value+")";
    setTimeout(function(){target.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255,255,0,"+(a_value -= 0.1)+")";}, 500);
  }
```

Comment: setTimeout runs once, setInterval runs multiple times.

Comment: `setInterval` is the function you are looking for

Comment: You really should do this with CSS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` only fires once. If you want something to keep repeating at an interval, then you should call `setInterval` instead. However, you should remember to cancel this repeating timer when your animation has finished.

When you call `setInterval` it returns a number that is essentially a handle to your timer. You can then cancel the timer later by passing this number to `clearInterval()`.

Here's a revised function:

```
function highlight(which)
{
    var target = document.getElementById(which);
    var a_value = 1.0;

    target.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,0," + a_value + ")";

    let handle = setInterval(function ()
    {
        if (a_value < 0)
        {
            clearInterval(handle);
            return;
        }

        target.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,0," + (a_value -= 0.1) + ")";
    }, 500);
}
```

However, the comments on this question are correct in pointing out that it doesn't really make sense to do this type of animation with JavaScript anymore. You should look into [CSS transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/).

Answer (score 0):

If You're asking about running same code periodically so - read about `setInterval`, `clearInterval` or make a method and call `setTimeout` inside of function again via passing period.

But if You're asking question about how to animate somethings, so - use css animations and don't "reinvent the wheel" (:

```js
function fadeIn(which){
    document.getElementById(which).classList.add("fadeIn");
}

fadeIn('fadeitin');


function fadeOut(which){
    document.getElementById(which).classList.add("fadeOut");
}

fadeOut('fadeitout');
```

```css
#fadeitin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f00;
  opacity: 0;
}

#fadeitout {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00f;
  opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

.fadeOut {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
  animation-name: fadeOut;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="fadeitin"></div>

<div id="fadeitout"></div>
```

p.s. You can use jQuery and `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` methods.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, `setTimeout()` only counts up to the time and fires the callback function once. But, you can make it run multiple times with a recursive function call. This is sometimes preferred over `setInterval()` because of the performance differences between the two.

```js
var a_value = 1.0;  // Needs to be outside of function to only be used once

function highlight(which){

    if(a_value < 0){ return; }

    // Instead of changing only the alpha of an RGB, just change the opacity
    which.style.opacity = (a_value -= 0.1);
    
    setTimeout(function(){
      highlight(which); // recursive call
    }, 500);
}

highlight(document.getElementById("test"));
```

```css
#test {
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

But really, this can all be done with a CSS animation and no JavaScript:

```css
#test {
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from { opacity:1; }
  to   { opacity:0  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```